# How can I fix this error implementing CommWeb on my website?

Tags: php, payment-gateway

I am trying to implement CommWeb on my PHP site. It isn't working. I am getting following error message:

> HTTP Status - 400
>
> E5000: Required field vpc_AccessCode was not present in the request

How can I fix this? I haven't found anything helpful in the documentation.

Here is my code:

```
  <?php 
        //Merchant Admin URL: https://migs.mastercard.com.au/ma/CBA
        //Merchant ID: TEST
        //Operator ID: Admin
        //Password: d#test
        // Access Code   AEFTEST  1A22FTESTTEST
            $session_id = 1;
            $finalprice = 50;
             $testarr = array(
            "vpc_Amount" => $finalprice*100,//Final price should be multifly by 100
            "vpc_AccessCode" => "AEFTEST",//Put your access code here
            "vpc_Command"=> "pay",
            "vpc_Locale"=> "en",
            "vpc_MerchTxnRef"=> "CLI".$session_id, //This should be something unique number, i have used the session id for this
            "vpc_Merchant"=> "TEST",//Add your merchant number here
            "vpc_OrderInfo"=> "1A22FTESTTEST",//this also better to be a unique number
            "vpc_ReturnURL"=> "http://localhost/test1/index.php/commweb/",//Add the return url here so you have to code here to capture whether the payment done successfully or not
            "vpc_Version"=> "1");

            ksort($testarr); // You have to ksort the arry to make it according to the order that it needs

            $SECURE_SECRET = "d#test";//Add the secure secret you have get

            $securehash = $SECURE_SECRET;
            $url = "https://migs.mastercard.com.au/ma/CBA";
            foreach ($testarr as $key => $value)
            {
            $securehash .= $value;
            $url .= $key."=".urlencode($value)."&";
            }

            $securehash = md5($securehash);//Encoding
            $url .= "vpc_SecureHash=".$securehash;

            header("location:https://migs.mastercard.com.au/vpcpay?$url");

            ?>
```

Comment: Please remove those credentials for security purpose as they are real merchant id , password etc.

Comment: You might wanna do a `var_dump($url);` to make sure it have the correct parameters. Also, remove those account details from your post.replace them with dummy data.